# How to return a void statement from -id in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, methods, void

In my code I run an -(id) code and the general method is to return a string or boolean value.  Is there a way that I can return a method instead?  In the code I have several 'if' statements, and would like each 'if' statement to perform another void function I have elsewhere.  So, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

without questioning the design…

you could return a block or `NSInvocation`.

Answer (score 1):

You can return a Block instead of id. Here you can find Apple's documentation about using blocks: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/Short_Practical_Guide_Blocks/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can return a selector (SEL), or better yet, a block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also return an (id) as response.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
```